# The minimal combination $\big|\pm p_1\pm\dots\pm p_n\big|$ for primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, computational-mathematics, conjectures

Conjecture:
The minimal combination $\big|\pm p_1\pm\dots\pm p_n\big|$ is $0$ for odd $n>1$ and $1$ for even $n$, where $p_n$ is the $n$-th prime.

Tested for $n\leq 17$ by me and for $n\leq 28$ by user AugSB.

---

> $\min \big|\pm p_1\pm\dots\pm p_n\big|=\frac{1}{2}\big(1+(-1)^n\big)$, if
>   $n>1$.

Comment: Obviously the number is optimal for odd $n.$ When $n$ is even, $p_{2},\ldots,p_{n}$ are all odd, so any sum of $n-1$ odd numbers is odd, and $p_{1}=2,$ so you end up with an odd number. Thus the minimum value is $1$ for even $n.$

Comment: @RideTheWavelet: my calculations suggests that the number is optimal for even $n$. Or do I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: My comment is that you have the optimal values in both cases, but that this follows just from the fact that $p_{1}$ is the only even prime (and testing for $n\leq 3$).

Comment: @RideTheWavelet: do you suggest that this proves the conjecture?

Comment: (As usual) the main thing to check is if the primes have anything special here, or if this is true (for $n$ large enough) for any sequence of odd integers with correct growth rate and gap.

Comment: @user1952009: of course it's true for a lot of sequences. What do you mean with "correct density and gap"?

Comment: With a correct gap assumption, you can show it by induction.

Comment: @user1952009: if you can prove the more general problem, why don't contribute with an answer?

Comment: I am contributing. What did you try given what we said ?

Comment: @Lehs True for $n\le28$.

Comment: @AugSB: what algorithm did you use? I just selected subsets of $\{p_1,\dots , p_n\}$ to represent the negative coefficients.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate), for any $n \ge 1$, $p_n<p_{n+1}<2p_n$. Using this I'll prove (by induction) :

> **Lemma :** Denoting $S_n := \Big \{ \sum \limits_{k=1}^n \varepsilon_k p_k \ |\ (\varepsilon_1,...,\varepsilon_n) \in \{-1,1\}^n \Big \}$, for $n \ge 6$, if $n$ is even (*resp. odd*), then $S_n$ contains all odd (*resp. even*) integers in $[\![-2p_n,2p_n]\!]$.

$ $

*Base case :* if I'm not mistaken, $S_6$ contains $-25,-23,...,23,25$.

*Induction :* assume the lemma to hold for some $n \ge 6$. I'll use that $\pm p_{n+1} + S_n \subset S_{n+1}$.

- if $n$ is odd : $S_n$ contains all even integers in $[\![-2p_n,2p_n]\!]$, and as $p_{n+1}$ is odd, $S_{n+1}$ contains all odd integers in $[\![-2p_n+p_{n+1},2p_n+p_{n+1}]\!]$, so by Bertrand's postulate, $S_{n+1}$ contains all odd integers in $[\![0,2p_{n+1}]\!]$. Similarly $S_{n+1}$ contains all odd integers in $[\![-2p_{n+1},0]\!]$.
- if $n$ is even, $S_n$ contains many odd integers, and $p_{n+1}$ is odd, so we find that $S_{n+1}$ contains many even integers (same thing as above). The lemma holds for $n+1$.

$ $

Hence for $n$ odd, $S_n$ contains $0$, and for $n$ even, $S_n$ contains $1$, which proves the conjecture.